# Blur effect background on all cell on UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiblureffect

I use Swift 2, Xcode 7 and Eureka! 1.2

I want apply the blur effect at cells of my TableView. I created the view that contains the effect. But how to recover all cells of the table?

My effect view :

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
```

When I change the style of a cell, this only applies to the first cell of this type ...

```
EmailRow.defaultCellUpdate = { cell, row in
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   cell.backgroundView = blurView
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don’t create a UIVisualEffectView for every cell—that’s hideously inefficient and will cause major frame-rate issues. Make a single one that’s the size of the table view, place it behind the table in your view hierarchy, and set the table view and its cells to have a transparent background color.